# Spring-security multiple authentication mechanisms with same credentials

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to use 2 authorization mechanisms simultaneously: LDAP and DAO.
They work in order of configuration. This is not appropriate if the user credentials match in both mechanisms.
(For example, in LDAP there is a user **m.smith** with a password **qwerty** and in the database there is a user **m.smith** with a password **qwerty**)
Is it possible to somehow convey the flag which mechanism to use at the current moment? Аnother mechanism in this case should be ignored.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


    auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .contextSource(contextSource)
        .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
        .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper);

    auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two mechanisms that are completely disjoint then you should probably fix it on upper levels (starting from UI). For instance if user uses LDAP authentication you would send a flag (for instance a HTTP header) that would indicate what auth type to use. Then you can implement custom filter that would perform specific type of authentication (programmatically).

I am not aware of any other solution that could do what you want in runtime.